# Are there Security Risks with Gravity Fields Dynamic Field Population?

Tags: wordpress, security, gravity-forms-plugin

When populating the values of input fields via parameters in a URL (dynamic population) in Gravity Forms, are there any security risks?

You do have to name the fields when editing the form in order for a parameter in the URL to do anything. And all it does is populate the value of an input field. But I wonder if this opens up any vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

> all it does is populate the value of an input field.

That's right, and before the value is sent to the browser it is always escaped by the appropriate WordPress helper function.